# Codeigniter inner join

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want data from three tables such as Ad_ID Title Price and from vehicle and mobile table and listing from ref_listing_type table

my code in controller is

```
$data['my_ads']=$this->My_Profile->get_My_Ads();
```

my code in model is

```
function get_My_Ads(){$query = $this->db->select('AV.Ad_ID, AV.Title, AV.Price, LT1.Listing','AMP.Ad_ID,AMP.Ad_Title as Title,AMP.Price,LT.Listing')
          ->from('ad_vehicle AV')
          ->from('ad_mobile_phones AMP')
          ->join('ref_listing_type LT1', 'AV.Listing_Type_ID = LT1.Listing_ID','inner')
          ->join('ref_listing_type LT' ,'LT.Listing_ID = AMP.Listing_Type','inner')
          ->where('AV.Created_By', $_SESSION['user_id'])
          ->where('AMP.Created_By','2')
          ->get();return $query->result_array();}
```

and my code in view is

```
<center><h2>My Ads</h2></center>     <?php if(!isset($my_ads)){?><span class="name">NO ATA FOUND</span><?php } else { $cnt = 1;?><table width="95%" style="margin: 0 auto;" lass="list"><tr><th>Sr.No.</th><th>AD ID</th><th>AD TITLE</th><th>PRICE</th><th>LISTING</th><th>Action</th></tr> <?php var_dump($my_ads); ?><?php foreach($my_ads as row){?><tr>    <td><label><?php echo $cnt;?></td><td><?php echo $row['Ad_ID'];?></td><td><?hp echo $row['Title'];?></td><td><?php echo $row['Price'];?></td><td><?php echo row['Listing'];?></td><td><a href="<?php echo base_url();?index.php/classified/MyProfile/edit_my_ad/<?php echo $row['Ad_ID'];?>">Edit</a> | <a href="?php echo base_url();?>index.php/classified/MyProfile/delete_my_ad/<?php echo row['Ad_ID'];?>" onClick="return areYouSure();">Delete</a></td></tr><?php $cnt++;}} ?></table>
```

and i got result

```
Sr.No.  AD ID   AD TITLE    PRICE   LISTING     Action
1   40  Pulsur  8788.00     Free    Edit | Delete
2   40  Pulsur  8788.00     Free    Edit | Delete
3   40  Pulsur  8788.00     Free    Edit | Delete
4   40  Pulsur  8788.00     Free    Edit | Delete
5   41  verna   65655.00    Free    Edit | Delete
6   41  verna   65655.00    Free    Edit | Delete
7   41  verna   65655.00    Free    Edit | Delete
8   41  verna   65655.00    Free    Edit | Delete
```

Comment: add a group by `->group_by('AV.Ad_ID'); `

Comment: dear friend plz mail me your id its tooooo urgent or cnt me omkarhendre89@gmail.com

Comment: if you have any question where you stuck you may add here as a question. Asking email etc over here is not allowed and your account will be deleted or flagged for doing so !!

Comment: in above result i want mobile result also what should i do

Comment: post your tables and some data in http://sqlfiddle.com so that the query could be constructed

Comment: i got my result n thanx for comment

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the type of join.

in the CI userguide:
If you need a specific type of JOIN you can specify it via the third parameter of the function. Options are: left, right, outer, inner, left outer, and right outer